# Ввод данных от пользователя

Tags: golang

Как сделать ввод данных от пользователя в *Go?* Хочу эквивалент как в *Python:*

```python
x = int(input())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как-то так:

```golang
var err error

var n int
_, err = fmt.Scanf("%d", &n)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

fmt.Printf("the answer is: %d\n", n)
```

Обработку ошибок делайте так, как вам нужно.